# stop read location after killing app objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

in my  objective c app, I use location tracking every 1 minute,

every one minute, the app read  the location and send it to the server using API, and send a local notification (to debugging).

the app works fine  when the app  is active and in the background  (without kill),

but when I kill the app, the location tracking stopped,

I read a lot of question here and nothing works fine with me,

this my codes >

1- The OS version is 14.

2- I included  **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription** & **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** & **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**

3- there are some codes in the app delegate,

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions {
    _locationManagerD = [[LocationManager alloc] init];
    [self.locationManagerD checkLocationAccess];
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center =[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate=self;
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application{
    // Clear Cache
    NSLog(@"applicationWillTerminate");
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    [self.locationManagerD startMonitoringLocation];
    
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground");
    [self.locationManagerD startMonitoringLocation];
}
```

4- I am sure to change the location permission to **always**

5-  I use the **LocationManager** file to start location tracking, this is the code
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mohmmed750/location_tracking/main/locationmanger.m

how can I read the location after killing the app??

Comment: I think enabling [background mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background) for location updates is the only option you have.

Comment: I make that, and nothing happen,,, the location stopped when I kill the app !

Comment: Does it work as you expect before you kill the app? In your code I sse a call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` which according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati) "generates update events only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected".

Comment: it works fine before I kill the app, but when I kell the app, it didn't work, even the location changes...